# How to access stateless component state inside window event listener?

Tags: reactjs

I have a stateless component which needs to listen on keyboard event. It adds `keydown` listener when the component is mounted and remove it when the component is unmounted. There is a state `test` is `boolean` value. It is set to `true` when the component is mounted. But in the keydown event listener, its value always `false`. It looks like the listener doesn't take the state reference. What's wrong with my code?

```
const { useEffect, useState } = React;


const Comp = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(false);
  const keyPressHandler = (e) => {
    setTest(!test);
    console.log(test);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setTest(true);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressHandler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', keyPressHandler);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="test">
      hello {test + ""}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-run useEffect when test change which will make the listener always have the current value.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setTest(true);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressHandler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', keyPressHandler);
    };
  }, [test]);
```

and you should remove the setTest from the useEffect since it will keep changing test to `true` whenever you use `setTest()`.